# Facebook Unity SDK ,me?fields=invitable_friends not working on iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, unity-game-engine

My facebook sdk 5.1.0, Unity 4.5.2f1
Platform is iOS.

I want invite my facebook friend to use my app just like "Candy Crush Saga" or "FarmVille 2" 
can get my all friends ,display them on custom UI and invite them to play app.
But I have problem getting friend list and setting custom UI.

using facebook unity example, it can get friends and send invite, but I can't get these info and it can't custom UI;

when facebook login , i get user_friends permission.
I can't use invitable_friends to get friend list, 
but "me?fields=friends" can get friends already use my app.

My login and get invitable_friend code:

```
FB.Login("email,publish_actions,user_about_me,user_friends,basic_info", LoginCallback);
...
FB.API("me?fields=invitable_friends.limit(10)", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, InvitableFriendsCallBack);
```

How do i get friends not play my app then send app invite?

edit:
when login on ios, I get error "FBLogin error".

Comment: Are you app a game that also have a canvas implementation?

Comment: thank you for comment.
I don't know what is canvas implementation.
Is canvas implementation can be created in unity or it's a canvas to launch app that jsut like facebook web canvas?

Comment: You should read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#invite_to_app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get friends, who doesn't play your game with iOS game. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/invitable-friends/v2.2

> The invitable_friends API is only available for games that have a Facebook Canvas app implementation using version 2.0 of the Graph API.

You may use `FB.AppRequest`to invite friends in game.  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.AppRequest